# CLion GDB received signal?

Tags: c++, gdb, sdl-2, clion

I am trying to run a very simple hello world for SDL. if I execute the program using 'run' it works fine but when I use 'debug' GDB complains about receiving `signal ?`. Not really sure what I am doing wrong here... I am also new to `CLion`

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED
#include <SDL.h>
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    SDL_Window* window = NULL;

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0) {
        printf("SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    } else {
        window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL Window", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 800, 700, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
        if (window == nullptr) {
            printf("Window could not be created! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        }
        SDL_Delay(2000);
    }
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(SkyGames)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(SDL2_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Packages/SDL2/i686-w64-mingw32)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR})

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp Math/sk_math.h)
add_executable(SkyGames ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(SkyGames ${SDL2_LIBRARY})
```

GDB output

```
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.11.1
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i686-pc-mingw32".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
[New Thread 6112.0x1444]
[New Thread 6112.0x30dc]
[New Thread 6112.0x130c]
[New Thread 6112.0x6b4]
[New Thread 6112.0x1820]
gdb: unknown target exception 0x406d1388 at 0x7626a932

Thread 5 received signal ?, Unknown signal.
[Switching to Thread 6112.0x1820]
0x7626a932 in RaiseException () from C:\WINDOWS\System32\KernelBase.dll
```

Comment: Is there any output in the console that pops out when starting a debug session? I mean regarding your `printf()` statements indicating some kind of initialization error. Also I guess the debug session suspends on signal, so that you're able to inspect frames and stacks of all threads, that might give you a clue on what's going on.

Comment: There is no output shown in the console after running a debug session and yes it does suspend on signal and it shows the output shown in the question. from what I can tell it is the gdb that ships with clion. I have switched over to `cygwin` for compiler and gdb and that seems to work fine. the only thing is from what I can tell `sdl2` doesnt work with it

Comment: Please, enable debug logging as described [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206560589-Debugger-doesn-t-stop-on-a-breakpoint-Debugger-shows-Command-timed-out-What-to-do-), reproduce the original issue to collect the logs, and upload the resulting `idea.log` file to https://gist.github.com/.